# Как определить браузер ие 7,8 с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript

Как определить браузер ие 7,8 с помощью javascript

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/#psj=1&q=Как+определить+браузер+ие+7%2C8+с+помощью+javascript

Comment: Почему я сначала подумал, что надо определить IE за 7 целых, 8 десятых секунды? о_О

Answer (score 2):

IE='\v'=='v';

Если это IE, то true, если нет, то false;

[Самый короткий способ определения браузера IE (влючая IE.8)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/50544/)